# Swift 4 / Xcode 9 new observe() KVO not type safe?

Tags: swift, swift4, key-value-observing

I have:

```
// ArticleModel.swift

class ArticleModel
{
    ...
}
```

and

```
// ArticleListViewController.swift

@objcMembers class ArticleListViewModel: NSObject
{
    dynamic var articles: [ArticleModel] = []
}

private var viewModel:        ArticleListViewModel
private var articlesObserver: NSKeyValueObservation?

self.articlesObserver = self.viewModel.observe(\.articles) // Crashes here!
{ [weak self] (viewModel, change) in
    self?.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

There are no compiler warnings.  Yet when I run this code, it crashes with:

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Could not extract a String from KeyPath Swift.ReferenceWritableKeyPath<App.ArticleListViewModel, Swift.Array<App.ArticleModel>>
```

This goes away with:

```
// ArticleModel.swift

@objcMembers class ArticleModel: NSObject
{
    ...
}
```

Why is this?  I understood that this new KVO form was fully type safe, then why was there no compiler warning?

Comment: This is a known bug: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5317